# Why is this not writing any contents to the file?

Tags: powershell

I am searching through my IIS logs for a certain string, from a list of strings. I want to output the results to a text file. The following code outputs the search results correctly to the console; when I re-direct the contents to a file nothing appears in the file. I am at a loss as to why this is happening, as all the guides for writing out to file make it appear simple.

```
$items = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
$searchresults = 'e:\temp\IISSearch.txt'
foreach ($item in $items) 
{
Select-String -Path e:\logs\*.log -Pattern $item | out-file $searchresults -Encoding utf8   
}
```

Comment: My best guess is that you miss the -append flag to your out-file and the last log file does not contain any of your search terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  $items = ('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
  $searchresults = 'e:\temp\IISSearch.txt'
  foreach ($item in $items) 
  {
  Select-String -Path e:\logs\*.log -Pattern $item | out-file $searchresults -Encoding utf8 -Append  
  }
```

or simply

```
   $items = ('123456', 'item2', 'item3')
   $searchresults = 'e:\temp\IISSearch.txt'

   $items | %{Select-String -Path e:\temp\*.txt -Pattern $_} | out-file $searchresults -Encoding utf8
```